# Access denied [403] when updating user accounts client-side in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm reading through the docs for Meteor [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) and the useraccounts package [here](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md) but can't find an answer. I've added the useraccounts package successfully and have created a few users, but now I want to add some data to the record in the collection for a given user.

For example, after account creation and login.  I want the user to be able to add/edit some fields on their record (short biography, etc..), but I keep getting a 403 error whenever performing a `Meteor.users.update(..)`.

My login config file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jxm262/65af9614e16b4e372a77).

The code that's causing an error:

```
Template.editProfile.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var profileInfo = {
            displayName: $(e.target).find('[name=displayName]').val(),
            tagLine: $(e.target).find('[name=tagLine]').val(),
            aboutMe: $(e.target).find('[name=aboutMe]').val()
        };

        Meteor.users.update(
            { _id: Meteor.userId()},
            { $set: profileInfo},
            function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('there was an error submitting editProfile data');
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    Router.go('profile');
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Doing console logs show the `Meteor.userId()` coming back correctly so I'm not sure what the problem is.  I'm assuming it's an issue with allow/deny but I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot.

The exact error is:

> error: 403
>
> errorType: "Meteor.Error"
>
> message: "Access denied [403]"
>
> reason: "Access denied"

Comment: I think you need to do collection.allow({update: blahblah}) on users mongo collection. The doc is here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

Comment: @matthias-eckhart , i see the question was edited a bit, but want to point out that I'm specifically asking this regarding the [useraccounts-core package](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core)  Nowhere does it mention setting the allow() anywhere on the client side when using this package (I think there may be some optional config I'm misunderstanding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By removing the `insecure` package, client-side write access will be denied by default.
If you want to allow clients to write directly to a collection, you need to define rules.

For example:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: ownsDocument
});

ownsDocument = function (userId, doc) {
    return doc && doc.userId === userId;
};
```

The `ownsDocument()` function checks if the `userId` specified owns the document. In addition to the `update` callback, you can set rules for `insert` and `remove`.

Read more about [Meteor's collection.allow(options)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow), access a [demo app](http://useraccounts-bootstrap-demo.meteor.com) or [clone the repository](https://github.com/MatthiasEckhart/meteor-useraccounts-bootstrap-demo).

Comment: The thing is, I haven't yet removed the insecure package.  I think this is something specific to the useraccounts package, or perhaps the default meteor 'user' collection.  Also, I've tried you're above and it's not working, although I do agree there has to be something blocking this during the allow/deny rules (perhaps some hook setup for the users collection?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue. I've created a micro app which demonstrates how you can change the user's name. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  The difference between your code and mine is this line - `$set: {'profile.name': username}`  .  So it looks like the `profile` field can be edited, but we can't dynamically add directly to the user obj?  example - `$set: {'myField': 'xxx'}`  Is this documented somewhere (perhaps I'm missing it)

Comment: That's right. If you want to add fields to user's documents you should use the `Account.onCreateUser` server-side hook. However, user's can create and update any data with the `profile` field. Read more about [Meteor.users](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users).

Comment: Ok, just reread through, have a much better understanding now.  Thanks!